# Register delegate-func by convention

Tags: autofac

On the `ContainerBuilder` i can do the following:

```
builder.Register<ScenariosConfig>(c =>
            (ScenariosConfig)c.Resolve<ConfigFactory>()
                  .Create(typeof(ScenariosConfig)))
       .SingleInstance();
```

With assembly scanning i can do the following:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(HasSingletonAttribute)
    .As(t => GetNameMatchingInterfaces(t))
    .SingleInstance();
```

Now the **question**: Is there any way to achieve the following: ?

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(... some condition)
       .CreateByDelegate((container, type) 
            => c.Resolve<ConfigFactory>().Create(type))
       .SingleInstance();
```

---

I've already found out about `IRegistrationSource` with which i can achieve something *similar*. However, I'm a bit skeptic about the performance impact of creating ton's of `IRegistrationSource`'s for each of my conventions which require a delegate for creation...
And also there's the fact that `IRegistrationSource` can't be used whenever you need to resolve all instances of `IFoo` which should be bound by such a "convention".

Answer (score 0):

In the end we did choose to use an `IRegistrationSource`. The only alternative i've "found" would have been to detect all types per reflection (not using autofac API...) and then generating a delegate for each and registering this with autofac. Would not really result in code that easily understandable...

So for completeness sake' here's the `IRegistrationSource` implementation:

```
public class ConfigConventionRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
       Service service,
       Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var s = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (s != null
            && s.ServiceType.IsClass
            && s.ServiceType.Name.EndsWith("Config")
            && !s.ServiceType.GetInterfaces().Any())
        {
            yield return RegistrationBuilder
                .ForDelegate((componentContext, parameters) =>
                              CreateConfigByFactory(componentContext, s.ServiceType))
                .As(s.ServiceType)
                .SingleInstance()
                .CreateRegistration();
        }
    }

    private static object CreateConfigByFactory(
                              IComponentContext componentContext, 
                              Type configType)
    {
        IConfig configFactory = componentContext.Resolve<IConfig>();
        MethodInfo method = Reflector<IConfig>
                                        .GetMethod(x => x.Load<object>())
                                        .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
                                        .MakeGenericMethod(configType);
        try
        {
            return method.Invoke(configFactory, new object[0]);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException tex)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo
                .Capture(tex.InnerException)
                .Throw();
            throw; // will not be reached as thrown above ;-)
        }
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```